Angular - Manipulate variables in template
I have the following code that create a 3x3 grid:
@for (i of [0, 1, 2]; track i) {
  <div class="row">
    @for (j of [0, 1, 2]; track j) {
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a
          [routerLink]="[
            mostViewedArticles[j].category +
            '/' +
            mostViewedArticles[j].id +
            '/' +
            mostViewedArticles[j].title
          ]"
        >
          <h5>1. {{ mostViewedArticles[j].title }}</h5>
        </a>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
}

The issue that I have come with the use of mostViewedArticles, I would like to have the indexes from 0 to 8 instead of 0 to 2, however this is not possible with the knowledge of Angular that I have.
Ideally, I would like to be able to declare a variable before the first for loop: let index = 0 and then increment it at the end of the second for loop: index++. This index would be used to access the data contained in mostViewedArticles. Like this:
let index = 0;

@for (i of [0, 1, 2]; track i) {
  <div class="row">
    @for (j of [0, 1, 2]; track j) {
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a
          [routerLink]="[
            mostViewedArticles[index].category +
            '/' +
            mostViewedArticles[index].id +
            '/' +
            mostViewedArticles[index].title
          ]"
        >
          <h5>1. {{ mostViewedArticles[index].title }}</h5>
        </a>
      </div>

      index++;
    }
  </div>
}

But it doesn't seem to be possible in Angular.

In Angular templates, you cannot directly declare and manipulate variables like you would in a JavaScript file. However, you can achieve similar functionality using Angular directives and template expressions. One approach to achieve your desired functionality is by using Angular's *ngFor directive and a separate index variable.

Local template variable are a long standing feature requst: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15280

We can just adjust the for loops, so that i+j gives you all the numbers from 1 to 8, please find below working example for your reference!
full code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
    @for (i of [0, 3, 6]; track i) {
      <div class="row">
        @for (j of [0, 1, 2]; track j) {
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <a
              [routerLink]="[
                mostViewedArticles[i + j].category +
                '/' +
                mostViewedArticles[i + j].id +
                '/' +
                mostViewedArticles[i + j].title
              ]"
            >
              <h5>{{i + j + 1}}. {{ mostViewedArticles[i + j].title }}</h5>
            </a>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    }
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  mostViewedArticles = [
    {
      category: 'test1',
      id: 1,
      title: 'test1',
    },
    {
      category: 'test2',
      id: 2,
      title: 'test2',
    },
    {
      category: 'test3',
      id: 3,
      title: 'test3',
    },
    {
      category: 'test4',
      id: 4,
      title: 'test4',
    },
    {
      category: 'test5',
      id: 5,
      title: 'test5',
    },
    {
      category: 'test6',
      id: 6,
      title: 'test6',
    },
    {
      category: 'test7',
      id: 7,
      title: 'test7',
    },
    {
      category: 'test8',
      id: 8,
      title: 'test8',
    },
  ];
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([]),
  ]
});

Stackblitz Demo
